# Mentioned Client name on CV, would be be a problem during the HR interview?

Tags: interviewing, resume

I'd worked with a leading IT Services company before, now on my CV I have mentioned one of the Client names that I had worked for a longer duration while I was with this company.

I've applied to various jobs with this CV and had never been asked on it. But, just wanted to check, if HRs should have problems on this. Does it raise a credibility issue?

I have seen many of my friends and even manager has mentioned about this particular project on Linked in and other networking websites.

It's been long time - I don't remember what was there in the confidentiality agreement when I joined **the company** - But I clearly remember I did not sign any confidentiality while I started working on this **client project**.

I have a HR interview coming up, If asked how should I answer it.

Comment: You don't remember what was written in the confidentiality agreement, but you also remember you did not sign any confidentiality agreement? :o

Comment: @ Happy ....Ok, Please don't vote down if you can't get what have I written. So, here it goes again, for you - I don't remember what was there in the confidentiality agreement when I joined the COMPANY, but remember clearly that there was no such thing when I started on this CLIENT PROJECT

Comment: I did not downvote because of that reason, but because you expect us to figure out what's written in your company's confidentiality agreement when we don't even know the company's name, instead of ... uhm, simply reading the confidentiality agreement yourself.

Comment: @happy I didn't expect that and certainly, no one does - I just wanted a general opinion or what else can I do if I don't remember?I've worked with multiple companies, and this was my first job. We're a bunch of 100+ freshers, who joined on the same date. and when you're just out of college, you follow what everyone is doing. And, that time I didn't except this to become so important.  and, one request for you, if you can't help, please don't  make such judgmental comments on questions . You've done better job with your other answers, sometimes you should just let go a few questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HR will not care**, unless the company you're applying to is the client.

If the relationship between the IT services company you worked for and the client is public, I see no harm in mentioning it on your CV.  But if the relationship is not public knowledge, it's the client and/or former employer that may be upset, not the new company.

In general, though, unless you happen to work in a field like web design where a public portfolio is important, naming the clients you worked for is just a waste of space.  A new employer cares about *what you can do for them*, not who you did things for in the past.

Comment: thanks, jpatokal! Yeah, then, I have nothing to worry about!

Answer (score 1):

The company you are applying to simply won't care.  They have no idea if you have signed an NDA or not with regards to previous employment.  Further, it's your responsibility to know what you can and can not divulge.

The company you used to work for *might*.  The only way to know for sure is to locate the NDA you did sign and see if it mentions anything about telling the names of their clients.  I will tell you that, generally speaking, NDAs do cover this sort of thing.  If you think you signed an NDA but don't have a copy then contact your previous employer and ask them for a copy of it.

If you think you signed an NDA then I'd remove it from the resume pronto until you are confident that it's not an issue.  Are you likely to ever be called on it?  Depends.  If the old company regularly searches through the 'net to locate mentions of themselves and their clients AND your resume is online then yes.  Any other situation is no.